# Weird behavior of timestamp size in hsqldb

Tags: hsqldb

I have sample ddl script:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON
(
  ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL
, FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
, LAST_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
, DATE_OF_BIRTH DATE
, GENDER VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
, SSN VARCHAR(100)
, LAST_LOGIN TIMESTAMP
, VERSION INT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
);
```

When I open this database in db visualiser I see timestamp has size 26 . I really dont know why because I read default is 6. So I want to change it for example:

```
, LAST_LOGIN TIMESTAMP(1)
```

now is size 21. This is really weird. Probably last integer mean size but what is the meaning of first number "2" ?

Answer (score 0):

What you call "size" is the subsecond precision of the timestamp, which is 6 by default. Your example of TIMESTAMP(1) defines a timestamp with subsecond precision of 1.

The number you see in DB Visualiser is the display size of the TIMESTAMP column.

TIMESTAMP(1), such as '2013-06-19 01:01:01.1', is always respresented using 21 characters. Timestamps defined as TIMESTAMP or TIMESTAMP(6) are displayed with five more digits at the end.